# Why am I getting Sprockets::FileNotFound

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, rake

I am pretty new to RoR and I'm trying to deploy an application on heroku. I'm trying to do `rake assets:precompile` but fails everytime with:

```
rake aborted!
Sprockets::FileNotFound: couldn't find file 'bootstrap'
  (in C:/Users/%User%/Documents/GitHub/appname/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css:13)

Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
```

This happens both locally and on heroku server. My application.css looks the following:

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the
 * compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any styles
 * defined in the other CSS/SCSS files in this directory. It is generally better to create a new
 * file per style scope.
 *
 *= require bootstrap
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */
```

My Gem file is the following:

```
    source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.1.5'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.1.4'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.2.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc



# Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
gem 'spring',        group: :development

gem 'wombat'

gem 'pry'
gem 'parallel'

gem 'chronic'
gem 'icalendar', '~> 2.1.1'

gem 'rails_admin'

gem 'tzinfo-data'

gem 'rails_12factor'

gem 'thin'
```

Does anyone know why its throwing the error saying it cant find bootstrap when I'm including the `bootstrap-sass` gem.

Comment: did you run `bundle install`?

Comment: @MichalSzyndel yep, not to mention the local server run fine, but when deploying to heroku rake assets:precompile fails. It also fails locally

Comment: Are you aware of this guide which says to `@import` instead of `require`? https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass#a-ruby-on-rails

Comment: I can't check with any of my apps because I'm using some exotic setups everywhere

Comment: @MichalSzyndel Just tried that, it messes up all the CSS (I didnt write the HTML/CSS). So not really sure whats going on.

Comment: Even if you make a file called `bootstrap.scss` and put `@import`s in there?